# How should I properly change the folder position of ViewController.m

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new here learning iOS development. After creating a project from the Xcode, I want manage the project to catalog the files.

When I put the autogenerated `ViewController.h` and `ViewController.m` into another folder(`./Controllers`), while the compiling is still finely working, the storyboard won't automatically open the code of the Controller connected to it.

Origin Folder Structure:

```
|- ViewController.h
|- ViewController.m
|- SceneDelegate.h
|- SceneDelegate.m
|- Main.storyboard
|- LaunchScreen.storyboard
|- info.plist
|- main.m
|- Assets.xcassets/
```

What I want

```
|- Controllers/
|  |- ViewController.h
|  |- ViewController.m
|
|- SceneDelegate.h
|- SceneDelegate.m
|- Main.storyboard
|- LaunchScreen.storyboard
|- info.plist
|- main.m
|- Assets.xcassets/
```

I've tried to change the ViewController property in storyboard file, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to do this action? Or is it not recommended to do that?

Comment: Storyboard never be disconnected like this. We did daily this, probably you are doing something wrong in other manner. Make sure if you'r creating physical folder then don't forget to check your folder structure in finder.

Comment: @dahiya_boy sorry for a misleading in the description, I'll fix it. What I meaning is in the Xcode, when open a storyboard after I moved the ViewController files, it won't open the code automatically. Where should I config it? Thank you for commenting

Comment: Did you meant by Xcode won't open the assistant editor of the respective controller that is selected from the storyboard?

Comment: @dahiya_boy Yep...

Answer (score 0):

- Assistant editor automatically finds file for you. If you select `UITableViewCell` in storyboard then it finds Cell class and controller class for you
- In some cases it opens interface builder file but you can find required file by selecting automatic.
- In case XCode does not find required class (Xcode is also a s/w, it might do misbehave). I did following in order.

  1. First make sure you have assigned class to your controller in storyboard.
  2. Close and reopen assistant editor.
  3. Close and reopen storyboard. You can click any other file and reopen the storyboard so that storyboard again loads in memory.
  4. If points 1,2,3 not working for you, then you can select your controller manually. Soon you will find Xcode automatically finds same controller for you.

**Note:** Changing the folder structure for the pattern architecture have does not to do anything with the assistant manager. Many times it won't work & trust me its normal.